# Customize color for individual Domain axis tick labels

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a JFreeChart which I'm running through a customizer (JRAbstractChartCustomizer). I have figured out how to color individual bars and item labels according to the data (eg green for >90%, yellow for 75-90%, red for <75%) by extending BarRenderer and overriding `getItemLabelPaint(int row, int column)` and `getItemPaint(int row, int column)`. Each bar has a corresponding tick with a String label, since the domain is by name rather than by numeric value. I need a way to individually color the tick labels based on the value similar to how I color the bars and the item labels.

What method do I override in BarRenderer, or what other thing do I do in my JRChartCustomizer to override the color on an individual basis.

What I'm doing for the item labels: (I want to do basically the same thing, but for tick labels)

```
class CustomBarRenderer extends BarRenderer {

    private final Color COLOR_GREEN = new Color(0, 227, 0);
    private final Color COLOR_YELLOW = new Color(247, 210, 0);
    private final Color COLOR_RED = new Color(237, 26, 0);

    @Override
    public Paint getItemLabelPaint(int row, int col) {
        CategoryDataset cDataset = getPlot().getDataset();

        if (cDataset != null) {
            Number itemValue = cDataset.getValue(row, col);

            String rowKey = cDataset.getRowKey(row).toString();
            String colKey = cDataset.getColumnKey(col).toString();

            if (itemValue != null) {
                int intVal = itemValue.intValue();

                if (intVal > yellowHigh) {
                    return COLOR_GREEN;
                } else if (intVal >= yellowLow) {
                    return COLOR_YELLOW;
                } else {
                    return COLOR_RED;
                }
            }
        }

        // if all else fails...
        return super.getItemLabelPaint(row, col);
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
        ... similar to above ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart's domain axis tick label is rendered by a [`CategoryAxis`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jfreechart%20CategoryAxis&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). You can use `setTickLabelPaint()` to color labels by category. The example below modifies `BarChartDemo1` to make the `"Test"` category label a shade of green.

[image]

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
domain.setTickLabelPaint("Test", Color.green.darker());
```

For finer control, you can override [`getTickLabelPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#getTickLabelPaint-java.lang.Comparable-) in a custom [`CategoryAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html) that has access to the dataset referenced by your `CustomBarRenderer`. The existing [implementation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#line.448) uses a `Map<Category, Paint>` as a lookup table. The `Map` is private, but the approach may give you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: That helps a lot! I don't suppose the category name can use regex or a wildcard? That would just be too easy.

Comment: Sorry, not that I know. You may be able to pass around a suitable `Function`, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37222598/230513), to ensure the same calculation in both places.

Comment: No worries. Your answer solved my problem very nicely.